# Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to do this:

```
UserLog.objects.filter(user=user).filter(action='message').filter(timestamp__lt=now)[0:5].update(read=True)
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken.
```

(using django 1.2.1)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As the error states, you cannot call `update()` on a QuerySet if you took out a slice.

The reason:

1. Taking a slice is equivalent to a `LIMIT` statement in SQL.
2. Issuing an update turns your query into an `UPDATE` statement.

What you are trying to do would be equivalent to

`UPDATE ... WHERE ... LIMIT 5`

which is not possible, at least not with standard SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see my error. Is there any workaround for this? (other than looping over the pks and updating each one?)

Comment: `UPDATE...WHERE...LIMIT 1` is possible in MySQL. Quite useful to avoid "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" locks.

Comment: @est you are right, I slightly expanded my answer. Note that OP never mentions the type of database that is used.

Answer (score 72):

The [documentation suggests](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) that something like the following *might* be possible - I'm not sure if doing the limiting in an inner `QuerySet` bypasses the check around calling `update()` after slicing:

```
inner_q = UserLog.objects.filter(user=user,
                                 action='message',
                                 timestamp__lt=now).values('pk')[0:5]
UserLog.objects.filter(pk__in=inner_q).update(read=True)
```

Failing that, you could use the [`in` field lookup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) like so:

```
ids = UserLog.objects.filter(user=user,
                             action='message',
                             timestamp__lt=now).values_list('pk', flat=True)[0:5]
UserLog.objects.filter(pk__in=list(ids)).update(read=True)
```

Comment: One probably should place these inside "with transaction.atomic():" block.

Comment: @DmitriySintsov why we need to place inside `with transaction.atomic()`

Comment: @DmitriySintsov There is only one update statement, there is no need to run within an atomic block.

Answer (score 5):

Since Django 2.2 you can use bulk updates :

```py
queryset = UserLog.objects.filter(user=user).filter(action='message').filter(timestamp__lt=now)
bulk = []
for userlog in queryset[0:5]:
    userlog.read = True
    bulk.append(userlog)
UserLog.objects.bulk_update(bulk,['read'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error when attempting to limit the number of records returned by a queryset.

I found that if we're using one of Django's [class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/) such as the [ArchiveIndexView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.dates/ArchiveIndexView/), we can use the `paginate_by =` attribute to limit the number of records.

For example (in views.py):

```
from django.views.generic import ArchiveIndexView
from .models import Entry

class HomeListView(ArchiveIndexView):
    """ Blog Homepage """
    model = Entry
    date_field = 'pub_date' 
    template_name = 'appname/home.html'
    queryset = Entry.objects.filter(
        is_active=True).order_by('-pub_date', 'title')
    paginate_by = 30
```

Comment: This is pretty nice and clean, as long as you don't want pagination. I guess you could also grumble that you're making the code unclear, since you're saying it's paginated but then not paginated it in the template, but it's a lot quicker and more easily apparent what's going on than other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to slice out some of the results of a queryset, you can copy it
it to another variable (a shallow copy is enough, which is faster
than a deep copy because it just uses references to the original
objects.)

```
import copy

queryset = Mytable.objects.all()
pieceOfQuery = copy.copy(queryset)
pieceOfQuery = pieceOfQuery[:10]
```

This will keep Django from complaining if you have an order_by filter on
your table, since that happens after the slicing if you do it on the main
queryset object

Comment: This is very inefficient as it would load all the items in Mytable.

Comment: and also produce a list and not a queryset?

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4286144/12120968) is the way to go. But if you're worried about race conditions, here's another alternative.

There's a `select_for_update()` method that locks rows when used inside a transaction. Here's [

> the link to the docs

][1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) and a related post in StackOverlflow: [Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285420/cannot-update-a-query-once-a-slice-has-been-taken)

So, for your use case, it would be something like this:

```
from typing import List
from django.db import transaction


with transaction.atomic():
    items_you_want_to_update: List[UserLog] = (
        UserLog.objects.select_for_update().filter(
            user=user,
            action='message',
            timestamp__lt=now
        )[:5] 
        # slicing evaluates the queryset and returns a list:
        # those row are now locked because of select_for_update()
    )
    
    for item in items_you_want_to_update:
        item.read = True

    # Using bulk_update() instead of .save() on each item to get better performance
    UserLog.objects.bulk_update(items_you_want_to_update)
```

Comment: The last line cause send an update on all `items_you_want_to_update` to DB you should store those 5 items in a list like @Lucas solution and then send it to bulk_update

Comment: Thanks for your comment @hamidrezasamsami. Fixed the code, so it should work now.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. From the Django documents: [QuerySet API reference - update](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-kwargs)

Answer (score -4):

Your code is incorrect because of where the slicing happens. It should happen *after* the call to `update()`, not before.

Wrong:

```
UserLog.objects.filter(user=user).filter(action='message').filter(timestamp__lt=now)[0:5].update(read=True)
```

Right:

```
UserLog.objects.filter(user=user).filter(action='message').filter(timestamp__lt=now).update(read=True)[0:5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Providing only codes as answer will not clearly help OP and readers to mark as correct answer. It will be appreciable if you provide why and how this code resolves the query. What changes you made in the OP's code so that the query is resolved.

Comment: I know that. but in my case, I do not understand his answer. then, I do that and my problem is solved. and my problem also the same. that's why I'm put here my answer.

Comment: This is an incorrect (possibly even dangerous) answer. The OP clearly wants to update the first five results. I'm pretty sure your code would update ALL results, THEN it would throw an error because `update` returns the number of rows, and you can't slice an integer.