# Django QuerySet update performance

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Which one would be better for performance?

We take a slice of products. which make us impossible to bulk update.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by("-modified_on")[3:]

for product in products:
  product.featured = False
  product.save()
```

or (invalid)

```
for product in products.iterator():
  product.update(featured=False)
```

I have tried QuerySet's in statement too as following.

```
Product.objects.filter(pk__in=products).update(featured=False)
```

This line works fine on SQLite. But, it rises following exception on MySQL. So, I couldn't use that.

> DatabaseError: (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support
>   'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")

**Edit:** Also iterator() method causes re-evaluate the query. So, it is bad for performance.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? And your second code block makes no sense. `iterator` doesn't exist by default, so is this something you added? And, an instance doesn't have an `update` method, so again, is this something you added?

Comment: My dev environment: Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7, Django 1.4, MySQL 5.5.22, python-mysqldb 1.2.3

Comment: That's not what you were asked.

Comment: Actually, I haven't implement iterator and update methods. They come with Django framework's core.

Comment: I am trying have only 3 featured products.

Comment: Don't see them in the Django codebase, so I'm going to say no, they don't "come with Django framework's core"

Comment: Please check following links; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: Okay. I missed `iterator()`, but there's still no `update` method on an *instance*. That's only available on a queryset.

Comment: @Chris Pratt Yes, you're right.. I guess, I run something else. I read that iterator() causes to evaluate the query again. So, It would be also a performance loss. Because of that I think first example would be better for performance. (And the working one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Chris Pratt pointed out in comments, the second example is invalid because the objects don't have update methods. Your first example will require queries equal to results+1 since it has to update each object. That might really be costly if you have 1000 products. Ideally you do want to reduce this to a more fixed expense if possible.

This is a similar situation to another question:
[Django: Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285420/django-cannot-update-a-query-once-a-slice-has-been-taken)

That being said, you would have to do it in at least 2 queries, but you have to be a bit sneaky on how to construct the LIMIT...

**Using [Q objects for complex queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):**

```
# get the IDs we want to exclude
products = Product.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by("-modified_on")[:3]
# flatten them into just a list of ids
ids = products.values_list('id', flat=True)

# Now use the Q object to construct a complex query
from django.db.models import Q
# This builds a list of "AND id NOT EQUAL TO i"
limits = [~Q(id=i) for i in ids]
Product.objects.filter(featured=True, *limits).update(featured=False)
```

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli: Are you sure its the same thing? Jan tried passing the limited queryset directly to a new queryset. In this example I am taking the id value list.

Comment: I am having following exception on the second line.
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'value_list'

Comment: @Jan: Sorry, typo. Should have been `values_list` with an "s"

Comment: @jdi that fixes the problem on the second line. But, I am having following message on the third line.. DatabaseError: (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it's acceptable to cache QuerySet in array

```
products = list(products)
Product.objects.filter(pk__in=products).update(featured=False)
```

Small optimization with *values_list*

```
products_id = list(products.values_list('id', flat=True)
Product.objects.filter(pk__in=products_id).update(featured=False)
```

Comment: You completely misunderstand the problem I had 3 years ago.