# Django Filter Query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to get the count of all packets which have `status = 'open'` from the `last 100` packets scanned.

Currently I do a sequential search,ie

```
packet_obj = Packets.objects.all().oreder_by('-time')[:100] # getting the last 100 packets

for packets in packet_obj:
    if packets.status == 'open' : count += 1 # comparing the status
```

**Is there a direct single query to get this count?**

Comment: WHy cant you just do `qs = Packets.objects.order_by('-time')[:100]` and `len(qs.filter(status='open')[:100])`

Answer (score 0):

in single line you can try this but instead of looping i think it not possible

```
packet_obj = Packets.objects.all.oreder_by('-time')[:100]
count=sum(1 for packets in packet_obj if packets.status == 'open')
```

additionally you can try this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285420/django-cannot-update-a-query-once-a-slice-has-been-taken)

Comment: Instead of applying a for loop ,Isnt there a query for this?

Comment: @user1162512 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285420/django-cannot-update-a-query-once-a-slice-has-been-taken

Comment: Thanks for the link. In the 2nd answer provided in the link with 27 upvotes, which one will be faster, using a loop as I'm currently doing or the answer itself?

Comment: I think its making DB calls twice. First when slicing and the other for the `in` query. Isnt using a loop will be faster in this?

Comment: @user1162512 yes you can try that .my sugesstion is stick with this . since there you need to call the db for two times.in answer it is one time . i think this will be faster

Comment: Same country same thoughts. Thanks for it. :) :)