# How to update a slice set, in an elegant way?

Tags: django, set, slice

First, I want the top 250 users, and update their `top = 1`

```
users = MyTable.objects.order_by('-month_length')[0: 250]
for u in users:
    u.top = 1
    u.save()
```

But, actually, I hope there is an elegent way, like this:

```
MyTable.objects.all().update(top=1)
```

And more, from this question: [Django: Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285420/django-cannot-update-a-query-once-a-slice-has-been-taken)

Does that mean CAN NOT WRITE `UPDATE ... WHERE ... LIMIT 5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the queryset has been evaluated once (at which point it will cache itself), slicing result in new querysets.  If the queryset has been cached, slicing is done using lists. At least the last time I read the Django code regarding this, probably around Django 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
users = MyTable.objects.order_by('-month_length').values_list("id", flat = True)[0: 250]
MyTable.objects.filter(id__in = list(users)).update(top = 1)
```

*assuming you have a primary key `'id'` in MyTable