# django manytomany field update

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a book which is contained in 3 categories.

Now i am making it possible to edit the book informations and also change the category. I am stuck in updating the categories of the book because there is ManyToMany Relation between Book and category.

here is how i am trying to update each category:

```
book = Book.objects.get(id=bookid)
newcategory1 = Category.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('cat1')))
newcategory2 = Category.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('cat2')))
newcategory3 = Category.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('cat3')))

book.cat.order_by('id')[:1] = cat1
book.cat.order_by('id')[1:2] = cat2
book.cat.order_by('id')[2:3] = cat3
```

but it is saying:

```
'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment
```

Relation

```
class Category(models.Model):
  CATS = (
    ('Art', 'Art'),
    ('Sport', 'Sport and Athletics'),
    ('Science', 'Science Discovery'),        
  )
  cat = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATS,unique=True)


class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.TextField()
  subtitle = models.TextField()
  cat = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

I am reading about `add()` and `remove()` methods.. how can I update the categories of the existing book with existing categories?

Comment: take look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011513/how-to-update-a-slice-set-in-an-elegent-way I think it would be helpful

Comment: This case of @EugeneSoldatov is not for Many to Many I guess... Anyway, as far I know you have two options, add and remove, or retrieve both objects, update/ save the related object and save the principal object...

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov i dont think, this thread is exactly my point. I think, i will just clear the all relations, (since there can be max. 3) and set them anew.

Comment: @Lara, yeah, i think i will go for remove and add again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far you know and I know the "remove" and "add" are the best options in this case.

For further information and complete examples about Many to Many Relationship in Django for you and others user who can may ask the same question, here is the link:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/